# Unable to read TX characteristic value of Nordic UART service, on Linkitone board as Central device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I am amateur for GATT and ble.

I am using **Linkit one** board as **central device** and **Nrf51** board as **peripheral** device. Central device successfully connecting with peripheral device, able to seach all Services UUID, Characteristic UUID, but it fails to read the characteristic value. Value which display on Linkit side it is not same as mentioned in nordic side.

I am able to get the characteristic value in nordic app and as well as nordic board as an peripheral device.

**Linkitone as central device fails to read TX characteristic value of nordic uart service** from any peripheral device. Even when I tried Linkitone as peripheral device and try to read the Nordic uart service value by nordic app, it fails. App get hanged every time.

Below I mentioned the value which gave to tx characteristic the value which is getting on central side. So is there any problem with Linkitone board with ble UART service or there is any different reason for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Is it a read response we see inside the red circle or a notification?

Comment: this read response.

Comment: I am able to solve this problem. One step I was missing after enabling notification, descriptor should be set and then Device is successfully getting tx characteristic value.